# Rails Devise rollback transaction doesn't give error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an application which uses Devise as authentication. I don't want user to be able to changed there email address. I've done this by setting the email attribute to read only in the User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_readonly :email
end
```

This works fine: Rails rollback the transaction. Devise however thinks that the update was succesful and displays a message succesfull message.

```
"Your account has been updated successfully."
```

I've tried several things including creating my onw methode that would return a flash notice but it keeps saying that the account has been succesfully updated.

Is there a way to raise an error when the record is not saved succesfully?

**Edit after Ashvin's anwser**. This is what I have in my model:

```
def email=(address)
  begin
    if new_record?
      write_attribute(:email, address)
    end
  rescue Exception => error
    flash[:alert] = error.message
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know I got your question or not, But from what I get following is solution. You can use exception handling while record is rollback

```
begin
    # do some stuff here
rescue Exception => e
    flash[:notice] = e.message
end
```

Comment: I've tried the code but it is still says that it's succesfully updating

Comment: What action you are performing, can you please paste code here, so I can get exact idea.

Comment: I've added the code custom code that I'm using. I'm think that it might be better to do a check in the controller if the email addres is different from the params[:email].

Comment: @Samuel if you dont want user to update there email address then why are you allowing him/her to update from UI, simply hide that input from UI.

Comment: That would be to simple. Eventhough it's hidden from the form you could still change it.